# Custom logging integer value to log4j2 jdbc appender in java

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j2, appender

I am trying to log my events in my database using `log4j2`. Specifically I am using `log4j2` `jdbc appender` in my properties configuration file for that purpose.
This is my appender in my log4j2 properties file:

```
# Custom log levels
customLevels = D
customLevels.D.name = ACTIVITY
customLevel.ACTIVITY = 50
# JDBC appender
appender.db.type = Jdbc
appender.db.name = databaseAppender
appender.db.tableName = db_name.test
appender.db.cf.type = ConnectionFactory
appender.db.cf.class = com.myproject.FactoryConnection
appender.db.cf.method = getConnection
appender.db.col1.type = Column
appender.db.col1.name = id
appender.db.col1.pattern = ${id}
appender.db.col2.type = Column
appender.db.col2.name = message
appender.db.col2.pattern = ${message}
appender.db.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.db.filter.threshold.level = activity
appender.db.filter.threshold.onMatch = Accept
appender.db.filter.threshold.onMismatch = Deny
```

I place the string id and message in a Map and pass them to my log as:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("id", "12");
    map.put("message", "this is test");
    LOG.log(Level.getLevel("ACTIVITY"), new StringMapMessage(map));
```

and it successfully logs it to my database.

Now my problem is I have set datatype of id in my database to be VARCHAR so that string can be sent from here. But my id in my database needs to be `INT(11)` type. And when I set that I cannot set logging as above since StringMapMessage only takes string values.

Now I cannot do this:

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("id", 12345);    //<<<send integer value
    map.put("message", "this is test");
    LOG.log(Level.getLevel("ACTIVITY"), new StringMapMessage(map));
```

I have been trying for hours using objectmessage and so. How can I solve this?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put it on integer. You can pass the numeric value in String while writing to the database it automatically converts to an integer. But if you put non-numeric value in int database field you will get an error like 'Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: 'non-numeric(maybe a)' for column 'column_name' '. So you be careful while passing String value to the integer database field.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("id", "12345");   //make it String log4j2 automatically configures to int in db
map.put("message", "this is test");
LOG.log(Level.getLevel("ACTIVITY"), new StringMapMessage(map));
```

Above example is the correct solution if you still get errors that may be due to the problem from other sides. Thanks.

Comment: wow thanks. I didn't know it would work like that. Now its working.